# Running Ansible playbooks on remote Vagrant box

Tags: vagrant, ansible, ssh-tunnel

I have one machine (A) from which I run Ansible playbooks on a variety of hosts.  Vagrant is not installed here.

I have another machine (B) with double the RAM that hosts my Vagrant boxes.  Ansible is not installed here.

I want to use Ansible to act on Vagrant boxes the same way I do all other hosts; that is, running ansible-playbook on machineA while targeting a virtualized Vagrant box on machineB. SSH keys are already set up between the two.

This seems like a simple use case but I can't find it clearly explained anywhere given the encouraged use of Vagrant's built-in Ansible provisioner.  Is it possible?
 Perhaps some combination of SSH tunnels and port forwarding trickery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this was surprisingly simple. Vagrant in fact does *not* need to know about Ansible at all.

Ansible inventory on machineA:

```
default ansible_host=machineB ansible_port=2222
```

Vagrantfile on machineB:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  ...
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", id: "ssh", guest: 22, host: 2222
  ...
end
```

The `id: "ssh"` is the important bit, as this overrides the default SSH behavior of restricting SSH to the guest from localhost only.

```
$ ansible --private-key=~/.ssh/vagrant-default -u vagrant -m ping default
default | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
j }
```

(Note that the Vagrant private key must be copied over to the Ansible host and specified at the command line).

Comment: having trouble trying to get this to work.  is the ansible_host supposed to be machineB or machineA.  also in my case, i have my vm a host name, so i assume i would replace 'default' with the hostname

Comment: In the inventory, `ansible_host` informs Ansible where to reach the target;  so it should be the hostname or IP of the Vagrant host.  `default` is the Ansible alias I've given to my Vagrant host (a poor name in retrospect).  It's the port (2222) which determines the Vagrant guest VM targeted.

Comment: ok thanks.  my confusion was that im running ansible and the target vm on the same box (for testing puproses).  so in this case the ansible_host is also my target and ansible node.